# Netgear Readynas changes permissions on it's own

Tags: windows, permissions, readynas

At work we have a netgear readynas duo that we use for different types of files. In one particular folder the user who tries to edit a document loses the rights to it. So if a user opens it and changes it, it cannot save it back. There has actually been a change in the permissions for that exact files with a new entry added only for that user which denies it.

This does of course create loads of extra work for us and I am starting to get sick of it. Do you know any way to make this go away? I googled a bit but did not find any problems that was like mine so I didn't wan't to do anything.